# Counting the number of unique items in an ArrayList

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to count the number of unique instances of items in an ArrayList without iterating through the entire list? Here is my code, and I would like to count the number of instances of Orange without iterating through the entire list - I am hoping there is a method to do it? In practice, the actual ArrayList will have hundreds of thousands of items.

```
Private Sub TestArrayList2()

    Dim TestAR As Object
    Dim Count As Integer

    Set TestAR = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    TestAR.Add "Apple"
    TestAR.Add "Orange"
    TestAR.Add "Orange"
    TestAR.Add "Orange"
    TestAR.Add "Pear"

    Count = TestAR.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't think there is a built-in method. You could use a dictionary but that involves a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a built in single function, but once the array list is sorted it's a simple case of locating the first (`.IndexOf`) and last (`.lastIndexOf`) occurrence of the string you're looking for:

```
lookingfor = "Orange"
TestAR.Sort
occurrences = TestAR.lastIndexOf(lookingfor) - TestAR.IndexOf(lookingfor, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Is there an online resource available that details all of the methods available to ArrayList? When I search for it, I find the methods that are available to the C# or Java implementation of ArrayList, which is not the same as that for Excel VBA.

Answer (score 4):

You could use .Toarray and then filter the Array:

```
Private Sub TestArrayList2()

    Dim TestAR As Object
    Dim Count As Integer, CountOrange As Long

    Set TestAR = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    TestAR.Add "Apple"
    TestAR.Add "Orange"
    TestAR.Add "Orange"
    TestAR.Add "Orange"
    TestAR.Add "Pear"

    CountOrange = UBound(Filter(TestAR.toarray, "Orange", True, vbTextCompare)) + 1
 'or Siddharth's

MsgBox Application.Count(Application.Match(TestAR.toarray, Array("Orange"), 0))  

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. Another way... `MsgBox Application.Count(Application.Match(TestAR.toarray, Array("Orange"), 0))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @GMalc: Not sure about it. THere is already an accepted answer. Also my answer is similar to EvR's answer. He might as well add it to his answer :D

Comment: @GMalc and SiddharthRout, Just added. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you really need it to be an `ArrayList` but you could use a `Scripting.Dictionary` like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub TestArrayList2()

    Dim TestAR As Object
    Set TestAR = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If Not TestAR.Exists(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
                TestAR.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value, 1
            Else
                TestAR(.Cells(i, 1).Value) = TestAR(.Cells(i, 1).Value) + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Dim Count As Long
    Count = TestAR("Orange")

End Sub
```